# Accessing XAML (WPF) elements in F#

Tags: wpf, xaml, f#, reactive-programming, observable

I'm trying to create a reactive application in F# using WPF and I have encountered some problems with accessing XAML elements from the code.

In the XAML-file I have created a grid containing 16 columns and rows each:

```
        <StackPanel Name="cellStackPanel">
        <Grid Name="cellGrid" Height="500" Width="500" Margin="10,10,10,10" Background="#CCCCCC">
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                <Border x:Name="border" Background="#FFFFFFFF" Margin="1,1,1,1">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"/>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="Black"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver"  Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#CCCCCC"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

In F#, I traverse through the grid and programatically initialize every cell into ToggleButtons:

```
    let initCell (x,y) (grid : Grid) =
        let cell = ToggleButton()
        Grid.SetColumn(cell, x)
        Grid.SetRow(cell, y)
        ignore (grid.Children.Add(cell))
```

Now I want to create an observable (to wait for in a recursive asynchronous loop) for clicking any of my ToggleButtons. I can access the grid element itself within the code but my problem is that I don't know how to access its child elements that I've created programatically. I was thinking of a, perhaps rudimentary, solution which is to catch the click event from the entire grid, and at the same time get the mouse coordinates to calculate which cell was clicked. But that is probably not a good way to do this.
I hope my question is understandable, otherwise, let me know.

Comment: you can loop `grid.Children` when necessary and retrive ToggleButtons

Comment: also: it is possible to create RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions in loop. Or just use `UniformGrid Columns="16" Rows="16"` instead of `Grid`

Comment: Why don't you use FsXAML + FSharp.ViewModule?

Comment: @ASh You are right, I guess I could loop through the Children UIElementCollection. But I'm not sure how to get their click events to merge them all together into one single observable. Could you provide an example of how to do this? Observable.merge only takes two sources, and I do not want to build a lengthy nested merge with hundreds of rows.

Comment: @FoggyFinder I'm not really familiar with FsXAML and FSharp.ViewModule. Would you like to tell me briefly how it solves my problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should start by looking into the MVVM pattern, to put it very very briefly, the idea is that you have a fairly strict separation of the code responsible for layout (XAML), UI logic and business logic.  It operates through data binding and results in you almost never needing to programmatically address UI elements.

Comment: @Filip Lagerholm , Sorry for the wait. Yes, it will be much easier. I don't quite understand what you want to get in the end. If you write more I can write an example.

Comment: I wrote the answer, if it's not quite what you wanted, I will edit it.

Comment: please do not ignore me. If my answer is not what you need just write about it.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Thanks for your response and for taking the time to help. I have not had the opportunity to test your solution yet. I managed, before you wrote, to get around my problem by using my second solution.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Instead of defining columns and rows manually and then loop through each cell to initiate buttons, I just observe the mouseDown event for the UI element, extract the mouse cursor position, and finally calculate the corresponding grid coordinates. It actually turned out very concise and dynamic. Conceptually, however, I believe that your solution can work. Unless someone else with similar problems find this thread and does it before, I hope to be able to take a closer look at what you are proposing.

Comment: Great. If ever you decide to use FsXAML or FSharp.ViewModule, then just do the ping in the chat - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f - I will be glad to help

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comment easier to use FsXAML + FSharp.ViewModule.

I don't quite understand what you want to, so a simple example:

```
 <Grid>
        <ListBox 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding N}" Columns="{Binding N}"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ToggleButton Content="{Binding Text}"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
                                  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}},
                                                    Path=DataContext.ClickCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=DataContext}"
                                  >

                        <ToggleButton.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                            <Border x:Name="border" Background="Wheat" Margin="0">
                                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"/>
                                            </Border>
                                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="DarkGreen"/>
                                                </Trigger>
                                                <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver"  Value="true">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#CCCCCC"/>
                                                </Trigger>
                                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </ToggleButton.Style>
                    </ToggleButton>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

You can use ItemsControl instead of ListBox, but configuring it will take some time =)

.fs:

```
type State = {mutable IsChecked:bool; Text:string}

type MainViewModel() as self = 
    inherit ViewModelBase()   

    let n = 16
    let data = [1..n*n] |> List.map(fun i -> {IsChecked = false; Text = string i})

    let click (state:obj) = 
        let st = (state :?> State)
        MessageBox.Show(sprintf "%s %b" st.Text st.IsChecked ) |> ignore

    let clickcommand =  self.Factory.CommandSyncParam(click)

    member __.ClickCommand = clickcommand
    member __.Cells = data
    member __.N = n
```

[image: Picture]

Thus, you can do anything with your object in the function `click`.

P.S. I allowed myself to change a little your ToggleButton style to the picture was more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of 3rd party solutions as an answer.  If I understand your question, you are trying to access an element that was specified in your XAML.  This can be easily done by converting your XAML to a string type then using:

```
let xamlBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xamlString)
let xamlStream = new MemoryStream(xamlBytes)
let xamlRoot = XamlReader.Load(xamlStream)
let rootElement = xamlRoot :?> FrameworkElement
let elementYouNeed = rootElement.FindName("nameOfElementYouNeed") :?> TypeOfElementYouNeed
```

Your case might be slightly different but this is the general idea.